# I want to run each PowerShell in the folder name that matches Excel column A

Tags: excel, powershell

questions 1.
The folder name is written in column A of Excel.
In column B of Excel, the file name to be modified for each folder is written.
There are a number of folders to run.
When the folder name in Excel column A is the same, execute the Powershell source in each folder.

Powershell source to run

```
$nr = 1
dir | 
ForEach{ Rename-Item $_ -NewName ( 'B column data must be entered_{0}.jpg' -f $nr++) }
```

That is, when the cell value of Excel A1 is the same as the folder name
I am trying to change the name of a number of jpg files in the file with the cell value of Excel B1 and add a number afterward.

questions 2.
The folder name is written in column A of Excel.
In column B of Excel, I wrote down the Powershell source values ​​to be applied to each folder.
The reason why you need to apply the Powershell source for each folder is that there are multiple folders in the folder and the names of each folder are different.
That is, when executing Powershell, the Excel column A value is compared, and when the folder name is the same, the Powershell source written in the Excel column B is applied.

In conclusion, questions 1 and 2 will give the same result.
It doesn't matter what you do.
To solve this, we try to execute a For statement or a Foreach statement.
Can you help.  please

Comment: Check out the module ImportExcel. It's very easy to get the data into PowerShell as objects then loop as usual, referencing the properties. Properties will be named after column headers by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to use data from an Excel sheet, here's a function that reads a single Excel sheet column and return it as array

```
function Import-ExcelColumn {
    # returns an array of Excel Column values
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$Path,
        [int]$WorkSheetIndex = 1,
        [int]$ColumnIndex = 1,
        [switch]$SkipHeader,
        [switch]$RemoveEmptyValues
    )

    # constants from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldirection
    $xlDown = -4121
    $xlUp   = -4162

    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $excel.Visible = $false
    $workbook  = $excel.Workbooks.Open($Path)
    $worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($WorkSheetIndex)

    # get the first and last used row indices
    $firstRow = $worksheet.Cells($worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).End($xlUp).Row
    $lastRow  = $worksheet.Cells($firstRow, 1).End($xlDown).Row
    if ($SkipHeader) { $firstRow++ }

    ### write-host "first: $firstRow  last: $lastRow"

    # collect the values in this column in variable $result
    $result = for ($row = $firstRow; $row -le $lastRow; $row++) {
        $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, $ColumnIndex).Value2
    }

    $excel.Quit()
    # IMPORTANT: clean-up used Com objects
    $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($worksheet)
    $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
    $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

    if ($RemoveEmptyValues) { $result = $result | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }
    # $result is an array. PowerShell 'unravels' arrays when returned from a function.
    # to overcome this, prefix the returned array with a unary comma.
    return ,$result
}
```

Having that function in place at the top of your code (and looking at your previous questions about this), you only need to read ColumnA in which the foldernames to process are stored.
At the moment, you have another column `ColumnB` that holds the powershell code to do the renaming of the files inside these folders. However, since that code is the same for every folder, you don't need that at all.
The code should rename every `.jpg` file in the folders to become `<directoryName>_<sequenceNumber>.jpg`, where  is a numeric value starting at 1 and incrementing as you go through the files and `<directoryName>` is the name of the file's parent directory.

```
# enter the full path to your Excel file here
$ExcelFile  = 'Full\Path\To\The\Excel\File.xlsx'
# this is the folder where all subfolder mentioned in the Excel file are
$rootFolder = 'C:\Image'
# read ColumnA (1st column) from the Excel file and collect the values in an array
$folderList = Import-ExcelColumn -Path $ExcelFile -SkipHeader -RemoveEmptyValues

# loop through the array of subfolder names and process each one
foreach ($dir in $folderList) {
    # combine the rootfolder and the subfolder to get a complete path
    $path = Join-Path -Path $rootFolder -ChildPath $dir
    # initialize the sequence number to 1
    $nr = 1
    # get a list of FileInfo objects of all .jpg files in that folder
    (Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter '*.jpg' -File) | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0}_{1}.jpg' -f $_.Directory.Name, $nr++ )
    }   
}
```